# Unit testing a Spring MVC controller that returns DeferredResult

Tags: spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to test a Spring 3.2.1 controller that returns a list of DeferredResult objects. I was using the following test as a guide, but I am wondering if this test is an integration test and not a unit test?

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/async/DeferredResultControllerTests.java

When I run my unit test, I get:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No async support in a pre-Servlet 3.0 runtime

In researching this error, I believe it has to do with the async support included in the servlet 3.0 api being needed, which makes sense, but what Maven dependencies do I need to include to make the test pass? Has anybody written a successful spring mvc *controller* unit test for DeferredResults like the one in the link? (Again, I am assuming that the link above is a unit test and not an integration test).

Thanks

Comment: Ok, my bad. I should have looked a little closer at the pom.xml file of the samples/mvc project. I needed to add:
  
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0.30</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

and then the test passed.